# Running unit-tests each time the target that they are testing compiled

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, target

I have a Xcode project with a testable target and unit-test target that tests it.
Now I can choose the unit-tests target and run the tests.
I want the the test will run automatically each time (after) the testable target is being compiled. Is it possible?

Comment: You mean after each build for the main target you want to run all the unit tests in the testable target?

Comment: @Alex.Pinhasov yes sir

Comment: My answer below didn't help you? If it did I would appreciate it if you could mark it as the correct answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Adding a Unit-Test Target to a Scheme** [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/04-Configuring_a_Scheme_to_Run_Unit_Tests/scheme.html)

> Before you can add a unit-test target to a scheme, ensure your project
>   if properly configured for unit-testing. See Setting Up Unit-Testing
>   in a Project to learn how.
>
> To add a unit-test target to a scheme:
>
> 1. From the Scheme toolbar menu, choose the scheme to which you want to
>       add the unit-test target.
> 2. From the same menu, choose Edit Scheme.
> 3. Select the Test action.
> 4. In the Test action Info pane, click the Add button.
> 5. Select the unit-test target you want to add to the Test action, and

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after doing some research this is what I figured out:

1) It is possible.

2) It extends the build time and therefore is wouldn't recommend it.

3) For some reason, it required me to switch back to "Legacy Build System".
[image]

**How to switch to "Legacy Build System":**

File -> Workspace Settings -> Build System

4) If you have a dependencies between your product scheme and the test scheme be sure to remove it.
[image]

**How to make it work:**

According to the documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2339/_index.html you can use "xcodebuild" and add a "Run Script" to build the tests scheme.

To add a script go to your project settings -> Build Phases -> "+" -> paste the code below and change the "myWorkspace" to your workspace name and "myWorkspaceTests" to your tests scheme name

```
echo "Unit-Test are about to start:  Started running myTests "

xcodebuild test -workspace <myWorkspace>.xcworkspace -scheme '<myWorkspaceTests>' -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone X,OS=11.4'
```

[image]